# my annual_inc column is not showing any graph, and am not able to understand what is the problem

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df=pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\ML\\XYZCorp_LendingData.txt", sep='\t',low_memory=False)

df['annual_inc'].head()
'''
0    24000.0
1    30000.0
2    12252.0
3    49200.0
4    80000.0
Name: annual_inc, dtype: float64
'''

sns.set(style="whitegrid")
sns.distplot(df['annual_inc'])
```

[image: actual plot]

This is the desired output, Which I am unable to obtain:

[image: desired plot]

Answer (score 2):

Income usually follows some kind of [pareto distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution) (Pareto is also known from the related [80-20 rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_principle)). This means a huge number of small numbers and very sparse  larger numbers, some of which can be extremely high.

Such a distribution doesn't lend itself well for a histogram nor for a kdeplot. Almost all values end up it the first few bins, with sparse numbers ending up in some of the last bins.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15468215/python-scipy-stats-pareto-fit-how-does-it-work) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242326/fitting-a-pareto-distribution-with-python-scipy) about why even just trying to fit some parameters can be extremely tricky.

Now, to get a reasonable histogram, one can limit the plot to just the first part. The number of bins needs to be incremented (because most will be cut off by the changed limits).

```py
x = np.random.pareto(1.4, size=1000)
ax = sns.distplot(x, bins=200)
ax.set_xlim(0, 10)
```

Alternatively, one could cut off all the high values and draw a default distplot. For example `np.percentile(x, 95)` calculates the 95<sup>th</sup> percentile.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

x = np.random.pareto(1.4, size=1000)
cut_off = np.percentile(x, 95)  # get the 95th percentile
sns.distplot(x[x < cut_off])
plt.show()
```

[image: example distplot]

PS: Note that the income for loan applications doesn't follow a strict Pareto distribution. The lowest incomes will be filtered away before reaching the loan application step, and the highest incomes don't obtain their loans via standard ways. Nevertheless, to get a nicer plot, limiting the range, augmenting the number of bins and experimenting with the bandwidth (`kde_kws={"bw":bandwidth}`) are still very useful.

Also for a violinplot, cutting off the highest values could be helpful. For the box plot, it would be better to just limit the x-range (`ax.set_xlim(0, ...)`. Optionally, you could try `ax.set_xscale('log')` to show the plot with a logarithmic scale.